# How to highlight search results views?

Tags: views, search

I created a view to replace the search default of my website. So I explained the form in a block. Everything works fine, but I would like to highlight search terms in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [Highlight](https://www.drupal.org/project/highlight) module. From its project page:

> - Highlight the keywords from referrer search engine
> - Highlight the keywords from local search

And I think that you should read this posts:

- [Highlight searched keyword using exposed filter views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/51444/28275)
- [Add Keyword Highlighting using Search API in Drupal 7](http://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/add-keyword-highlighting-using-search-api-drupal-7)