# How to enable highlighted search functionality?

Tags: 7, search

I want to enable search functionality such that:

1. I have one word say "school" in my website and if I put "sc" word in search box, then search result should give "school" word with "sc" word highlighted.
2. I have one word say "school" in my website and if I put "oo" word in search box, then search result should give "school" word with "oo" word highlighted.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 5,, or any release above it?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: yes its solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Highlight](https://www.drupal.org/project/highlight) module:

> - Highlight the keywords from referrer search engine
> - Highlight the keywords from local search

If you need more information you can read this posts:

- [Highlight searched keyword using exposed filter views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/51444/28275)
- [Add Keyword Highlighting using Search API in Drupal 7](http://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/add-keyword-highlighting-using-search-api-drupal-7)